# How to make flexible only distribute empty space in Column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a column with 2 children. The first child has a fixed height, and the second child has dynamic content.

[image: Two children]

I want the first child to be at the head of the screen, and the second child to be in the vertical middle.

So i added an empty third child and made the first and third child Flexible so that they shared vertical space equally:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Column(
        children: [_firstChild()],
      ),
    ),
    _secondChild(),
    Flexible(child: Container()),
  ],
)
```

This works when the content of the second child is short.

[image: Small second]

But if the second child gets tall, it clips the first child:

[image: Tall second]

Isn't the `Flexible` supposed to distribute only the empty space when `fit: FlexFit.loose`? I tried both the `fit` possibilities. I've tried to put the first child inside a `SizedBox` and an `Align`

I've tried to make the third child a `Spacer`. Nothing has worked so far. The empty third child is taking half of the remaining vertical space.

**EDIT:**

When the second child's height is too much to make it vertically centered without clipping the first child, i want it to just behave like a default `Column` with `MainAxisAlignment.start` (like the first image)

Comment: What do you want in the second case? Is `Center` and `Stack` ok for you?

Comment: Oh if use `Stack` and `Center`, the second child will overlap the first child. If the second child is too tall, i want it to just sit under the first child. It no longer needs to be in the center.

Comment: Essentially, i want the second child to be vertical center if there's space, and if not i want it to be directly under the first child.

Comment: then see my ans

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
Stack(children:[
  Center(child: SecondChild()),
  Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, child: FirstChild()),
])
```

Comment: Hey that's what i replied to in the comment. If the `SecondChild()` gets too tall, it will overlap the `FirstChild()`. I want the `SecondChild()` to behave like the first picture if it's too tall. That's what i was hoping with the two `Flexible` blocks.

Comment: @alokraop answer edited (swap the order). is this ok?

Comment: Now the `FirstChild()` will overlap the `SecondChild()` i don't want any content to be overlapped. If the the `SecondChild()` is too tall to be in the center of the vertical axis, i want it to be under the first child. Can't achieve that with a stack.

Comment: @alokraop confused... could you please give some explanations or screenshots of what you want